# Why Objective-C doesn't show output frames of a video captured by OpenCV?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I am new to Objective C and I would like to use Opencv to capture the video and process each frame. The output of each frame should be displayed on the screen (ios simulator).

The code in ViewController.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    cv::Mat cvImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;

@end
```

The code in ViewController.m is

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "opencv2/highgui/ios.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture cap(VIDEO_PATH);
    int count = 0;
    if(!cap.isOpened()){
        cout << "bad frame!!!!" << endl;
    }
    while(1){
         if(!cap.read(frame)){
            cout << "cannot read " << endl;
            exit(0);
         }

        cout << count++ << endl;
        imageView.image = MatToUIImage(frame);
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150); // pass your frame here
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    }
}
...
@end
```

If I remove while loop, the simulator will display the first frame from the video, which is reasonable. But if I have while loop, in the output console, the number of frames is counting, which means the program is reading frames from the video but in ios simulator, there is nothing....

Since I want to process every frame based on OpenCV, how can I display every frame after I captured using OpenCV and processed it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add a new subviews each frame. Just set the image into the existing view.

Comment: Thx! So how can I change my code? Just delete [self.view addSubview:imageView]; ?

Comment: Store the image into view.image, delete the subview stuff

Comment: After deleting subview stuff, I just used imageView.image = MatToUIImage(frame). but I got nothing on the simulator, just as before, and the frame counter is still increasing....

Comment: How did you confirm you're getting subsequent frames to store in the view? What kind of view is it?

Comment: I have fixed my problem using NSTimer and [imageView setNeedsDisplay]! Thank you all the same!